# xsd restrict explicit combinations of values

Tags: xsd

I want to restrict different combinations of values. What I have is a Problem similar to:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CarTypes">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string"
       <xs:enumeration value="VW" />
       <xs:enumeration value="BMW" />
       <xs:enumeration value="HONDA" />
       <xs:enumeration value="MECREDES" />
       <xs:enumeration value="ALL" />
       <xs:enumeration value="DEFAULT" />
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I want to restrict the following combinations:

```
"ALL" and "EVERY OTHER CAR" -> NOT ALLOWED
```

but not

```
"ALL" and "DEFAULT" -> ALLOWED
```

I am not very familiar with xsd syntax so I hope there is a way to do that smart, otherwise I have to restrict every single combination.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the name of the simple type definition should be 'CarType' not 'CarTypes' (an element or attribute based on that type can represent exactly one type of car).

If you want to represent multiple types of car (e.g. "VW BMW MERCEDES") then you need a simple type list (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ListDt). That list type could be called 'CarTypes' because it could represent multiple space-separated car types.

You will not find it easy to restrict the combinations of car types in the way that you describe. It would probably be easier to change the data model ('ALL' and 'default' are not really types of car), or implement those rules in code. Although, somebody who knows XML Schema 1.1 better than me might have a solution.